# Scrapy pipeline to mysql Error 1241

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy, python and mysql so forgive me if this is simple. I believe I have a syntax problem but I don't know enough yet to fix it. I get "Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)" when I try to scrape with this pipeline and nothing is passed to the database.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='user', passwd='pass', db='db', host='host', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table (1, 2, 3, 4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (item['1'], item['2'], item['3'], item['4']))
        self.conn.commit()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `table` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (item['1'], item['2'], item['3'], item['4']))
```

Comment: If i do that i get this error "Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table' (1, 2, 3, 4) VALUES (('1' at line 1" the server version is 5.5.37-35.0 if that helps.

Comment: It works for me, if there is a table named **table** which has four columns named 1 2 3 4.

Comment: That is how I have it set, maybe I setup the sql server wrong could you tell me the settings you used. I just need it to store strings of text.

Comment: Notice that: the mark around **table** and **1** **2** **3** **4** is backtick not single quote mark. Maybe you mistook this.

Comment: I did, that was stupid. But now I am back to "Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)" again though.

Comment: So I just tried this. I took off the end , (item['1'], item['2'], item['3'], item['4']) and just put them in for (%s, %s, %s, %s) so its (1, 2, 3, 4) and now i get no error but nothing is going to the db. Very frustrating.

Comment: If you put the values of item['1'] into the insert string, you need to quote them since there are strings, like this: `"""INSERT INTO \`table\` (\`1\`, \`2\`, \`3\`, \`4\`) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'd', 'd')"""`

Comment: So what's value of `item['1']`?

Answer (score 0):

This line still won't put anything into the db 1 is just the word link it would be a url to a video.

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `table` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (item['1'], item['2'], item['3'], item['4']))
```